Is it possible to connect Excel / Power BI to an Oracle database without having an Oracle account?
I am new to the Oracle Database. Is it possible to directly connect Excel/Power BI to an Oracle database (Excel-> Data tab -> Get Data -> From Database -> From Oracle Database) without having an Oracle account? I have installed the Oracle client and am able to connect to the Oracle Database using ODAC.

Simple answer: No this is not possible, you need an account.

How did you achieve "am able to connect to the Oracle Database using ODAC." without having an account?


installed Oracle Instant Client and ODBC Driver
Configure the Oracle ODBC Driver: type ‘ODBC Data Sources’ in the Start menu, go to the ‘system DSN’ or “User DSN’ tab and click ‘Add’.  Select ‘Oracle in instantclient example: Oracle in OraClient12Home1 from the list and click Finish.
Configure the DSN (Data Source Name): enter a name for DSN, in the ‘tnsnames.ora’file, enter the network service name of the Oracle database. Click ‘test connection’ to verify the connection details.


"I'am able to connect to the Oracle Database using ODAC" = you have an Oracle account.
